What, precisely, is a stratification of a stack?
I'm currently working on a structure result for a certain spectral moduli problem, and I've been running into the problem of having to define what, precisely, is meant by the term "stratification". Some candidates:

A stratification of an algebraic stack is a stratification of its space of points as a topological space. This is probably the most straightforward definition, and it extends to arbitrary stacks and even presheaves. A major downside, though, is that it doesn't specify the strata as stacks. There are of course many different substacks of a given algebraic stack (or even scheme) which have the same subspace of points. It's also not totally clear to me whether it implies the following definition, which should at least hold for any stratification.

A stratification of a stack is a stratification of its category of quasicoherent sheaves in the sense of Ayala-Mazel-Gee-Rozenblyum. This definition comes from their paper Stratified Noncommutative Geometry, and is very well-behaved for computation and for use in homotopy theory (which is my goal). Even if it isn't the right definition, it should at least be a property of stratified stacks. However, it has a glaring problem: a stack is not actually specified by its category of quasicoherent sheaves. The moduli stack of oriented elliptic curves, for example, has the same module category as $TMF$ despite not being affine. So this doesn't seem like it can be a complete definition.


My archetypical example is the moduli stack of formal groups (either the classical or the spectral version), which plays a central role in chromatic homotopy theory. The height stratification of the p-local moduli stack of formal groups is a stratification of the space of points, and also gives rise to algebraic properties which are used to much effect when studying $K(n)$-local spectra and the like. The formal description of this stratification is given in terms of a presentation for $\mathcal{M}_{fg}$ as a Hopf algebroid: the $n$th object in the filtration is the substack corresponding to the quotient $L/(p,v_1,\dotsc,v_{n-1})$ ($L$ being the Lazard ring). Unfortunately, this definition only works for stacks which admit a presentation via a Hopf algebroid, which many do not. (They have to be pretty close to representable for this to work.)
A bit of Googling and skimming some papers on the arXiv suggests that there is a notion of stratification that is standard among (some subset of) algebraic geometers. (Standard enough that they don't bother to define it, at least.) And the fact that stratifications are so often used to study algebraic properties of algebreo-geometric objects seems to indicate that there is some reasonable definition out there. In particular, I expect there is some definition that (1) implies the two candidate definitions I've described above and (2) generalizes the example of the height stratification. It is with all this in mind that I put to you the question: what, precisely, is a stratification of a stack?

I would have thought that the correct notion would be a collection of locally closed substacks such that on the level of points they induce a stratification of the underlying topological space. This seems to be the convention here for example:
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06RB
Or do you not like this definition for non-reduced stacks?

@DanielLoughran It is indeed the non-reducedness that is my issue. Spectral stacks are very non-reduced, in that their reduction is a classical stack, so it's important to keep track of this information.
I'm also concerned about whether that definition will induce a stratification on the category of quasicoherent sheaves. It's possible that it will, but it's certainly not obvious to me.

@DanielLoughran Wait, are you suggesting that the choice of substack should be part of the data and the ramification of the underlying topological space a condition? Because that might work out nicely, actually. Though I'm still not sure how QCoh would behave.

These issues regarding non-reducedness are already present for schemes, let alone stacks. Given that a stratification is purely topological in nature and a closed subset has multiple scheme structures in general, it makes sense to proceed as I suggest. I.e. for schemes a stratification is a collection of locally closed subschemes which induce a stratification of the underlying topological space; similarly for stacks.
